# Remove punctuations with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I tried the following but it

```
s = '白云区H(52)077楼盘'

''.join(re.findall(u'([\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]|(?<=[0-9])[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+(?=[0-9]))', s))
```

But I got `白云区H52)077楼盘` instead of `白云区H52077楼盘`

What is the correct approach?

Thanks.

Comment: try myString.translate(None, string.punctuation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my understanding, you could do:

```
print(re.sub(u'[^\w\s]', '', s))
```

Which outputs:

```
白云区H52077楼盘
```

Comment: This will remove much more than punctuation. For example `&`, `+`, `%`...

Answer (score 0):

Try use something like this:

```
replace('白云区H(52)077楼盘', @'[\(\)]', '')
```

Good Luck!